# Pycharm is not showing result

Tags: python

Pycharm is not showing result
Process finished with exit code 1

[image]

but when i debug its working and shows a warning:

```
Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3\helpers\pydev\setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: process 6496 is connecting.
```

[image]

Comment: hover over your python file, right click then click on "Run" I have assumption that your `print "hello"` file is not actually in check.py. This very common when your new to PyCharm

Comment: when i run through IDLE it's working fine..but the issue is with pycharm. it's not printing the result..

Comment: you can check by adding the project interpreter from the settings. like `file>settings>project_name>project interpreter` add the interpreter and run again. hope this will help

Comment: i tried that also..i installed 2 interpreters. one is 2.7.11 and 2.7.13. versions of python. i selected 2.7.13 version and my pycharm is 2017.1.3 version..none of them works ..

Comment: in pycharm `Run>Edit Configuration` than check if all parameter

Comment: I actually have the same issue right now. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

check Run>Edit Configurations..> Select Emulate terminal in output console(make it selected...)so that it can print @console output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, and  i tried to run it but I am still getting the message - Process finished with exit code 0

```
from math import exp

def future_discrete_value(x, r, n):
    return x * (1 + r) ** n

def present_discrete_value(x, r, n):
    return x * (1 + r) ** -n

def future_continuous_value(x, r, t):
    return x * exp(r * t)

def present_continuous_value(x, r, t):
    return x * exp(-r * t)

if __name__ == '__main()__':
    # value of investment in dollars
    x = 100
    r = 0.05
    n = 5

    print("Future value (discrete model) of x: %s" + future_discrete_value(x, r, n))
    print("Present value (discrete model) of x: %s" + present_discrete_value(x, r, n))
    print("Future value (continuous model) of x: %s" + future_continuous_value(x, r, n))
    print("Present value (continuous model) of x: %s" + present_continuous_value(x, r, n))
```

I am using the below version

PyCharm 2023.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-232.10072.31, built on October 12, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.8.1+7-b1000.32 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).