# parsing the soup in the python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am new in Python programming and I am learning it from Udemy website's courses. 
In one of the videos ( parsing the soup ), the instructor writes some code and gets a result. But the problem is whenever I want to run the same code on my computer, I do not get the same result as the instructor. actually the result is nothing. I uploaded the screenshot of the instructor's code and result. here is my code below:
would you help me to find the solution, please?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

search = input("what do you want to search : ")
params = {"q": search}

r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("ol", {"id": "b_results"})
links = results.findAll("li", {"class": "b_algo"})

for item in links:
    item_text = item.find("a").text
    item_href = item.find("a").attrs["href"]

    if item_text and item_href:
        print(item_text)
        print(item_href)
```

[Click here to see the Instructor's code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVqet.jpg)

[Click here to see my code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Clc3.jpg)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem appears to be with the way you've set up PyCharms. The output is being printed to the 'terminal'. Check if this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172898/pycharm-is-not-showing-result solves your problem.

Comment: Consider using a text editor to write your programs and a `cmd.exe` window to run them. IDE's like pycharm can interact with Python in ways that are surprising and hard for a new programmer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution and the reason why the code did not give me any answer.
I am from Iran and the internet services are under the control and some of the websites like Facebook, Youtube, etc. are banned and blocked. so many other websites too.
because of this problem people have gotten used to using VPN services and WHEN I CONNECT my Windows to any VPN and run the code, the code runs well without any problem.